# Adding checkbox dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this](https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector/blob/master/jquery.facebook.multifriend.select.js) jQuery plugin to generate custom facebook friend selector. Below is the code which is generating each friend div (line 86). [Link](https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector/blob/master/jquery.facebook.multifriend.select.css) to the css

```
$.each(sortedFriendData, function(i, friend) {
                    selectedClass = (friend.id in preselected_friends_graph) ? "selected" : "";
                    buffer.push("<div class='jfmfs-friend " + selectedClass + " ' id='" + friend.id  +"'><img/><div class='friend-name'>" + friend.name + "</div></div>");
            });
            friend_container.append(buffer.join(""));

            uninitializedImagefriendElements = $(".jfmfs-friend", elem);            
            uninitializedImagefriendElements.bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
                if( $(this).attr('src') === undefined) {
                    $("img", $(this)).attr("src", "//graph.facebook.com/" + this.id + "/picture");
                }
                $(this).unbind('inview');
            });
```

Here I am trying to add checkbox in front of each image. IN this there will be a checkbox, image and name in a single line. I tried adding checkbox like this

```
buffer.push("<div class='jfmfs-friend " + selectedClass + " ' id='" + friend.id  +"'><input type='checkbox'/><img/><div class='friend-name'>" + friend.name + "</div></div>");
```

and added `display:inline-block` for the div css.

Whatever I do image always comes first. Even if add element before `<img/>.` Please help

Comment: inspect css in browser console. Sounds like `img` has float or absolute position

Comment: yes img has float:left; property.

Comment: adjust css accordingly then

Comment: yup. It worked out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removal of `float:left` property did the trick.